# importing interface with require() in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using TypeScript but due to some other code I am interacting with I need to use require instead of import.

When I try and use an interface from a require'd module I get a "Cannot find namespace" error. Is there a way to use an interface from a require'd module or is import the only way that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More context is needed to see what’s going wrong in your case. Post some example code please, and precisely which module you’re importing/requiring.

Meanwhile I’d like to point out that, in TS there’s a commonjs compliant module syntax that goes like:

```
import myModule = require("some_module")
```

You might want to try it. See if problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you - that syntax has turned around a very frustrating few days and saved my sanity just a bit.